# Merging tags mingw64 with mingw-w64, and mingw32 with mingw

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I've just edited the wiki for the mingw64 tag just to find there is a mingw-w64 tag.

Am I missing something or can those be merged?

---

Currently there are [mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw) [mingw32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw32) [mingw64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw64) [mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw-w64) tags.

MinGW64 is certainly a misspelling (contraction if you may) of the official name MinGW-w64, so i believe the tags should be merged to mingw-w64

MinGW32 was the old name of MinGW, so there's no room for doubt. I believe the perpetuation of this tag-usage is to explicit differ from MinGW-w64, but this leads to more confusion than clarification. (it's wiki already recommend it's non-usage... So why maintain it?)

---

[mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw) + [mingw32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw32) -> [mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw)

[mingw64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw64) + [mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw-w64) -> [mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw-w64)

Comment: Well, which one is more accurate? [tag:mingw64] would match the [tag:mingw32] tag that also exists. Does the second "w" need to be in there? We don't know much anything about this product so we need more information to tag it properly.

Comment: Correct. What a mess. MinGW-w64 is the accurate, official name of the product/suite. MinGW32 does not exist (I guess the MinGW32 tag refers to the older MinGW (which also happens to be an existing tag, probably referring to both)). I will look for all the mess I can find, edit the question with suggestions, and poke a moderator... you =)

Comment: Probably the [tag:mingw32] tag should be merged with and/or aliassed to the [tag:mingw] tag.  The [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) site houses the (32-bit) MinGW code; the [MinGW-W64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) name suggests that [tag:mingw-w64] is the more appropriate tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed.

Comment: @animuson Suggestion fully formulated.

Comment: @animuson Is there anybody from SE following up on this tag duplication?